# Is it possible to apply a meta_query to one specific post type in a query with multilple post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, meta-query

I have two post types, *news* and *events* :

- A *news* has no custom fields.
- An *event* has two custom fields : *start-date* and *end-date*.

I want to display *news* and *events* on the same page, ideally with one single query.

One important fact is that *events* have to be ordered by *end-date* and that only future or current *events* have to be displayed.

Here's the query args I am trying :

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'news', 'events' ),
    'meta_key' => 'end-date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array( 
            'key' => 'end-date',
            'value' => date ( 'Ymd' ),
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare' => '>='
        )
    )
);
```

That works fine for *events* alone, but doesn't when I add *news* to the post types.

The problem seems to be that I specified 'meta_key' and 'meta_query' parameters which are only present on *events*, as a result all the *news* are left out in the results.

So my question is, is there a way to target a *meta_query* to one specific *post_type* in one same query ?

Comment: Have you tried with the `relation` parameter, [link to the docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)?. You could run into problems with the `orderby`

Comment: Indeed, as I order by a meta field that exists only on events, all news are discarded from the results.

Comment: why not create 2 loops?

Comment: I'd like to have one loop so I can show the two kinds of posts in the same list with pagination.

Answer (score 3):

You can add another array into your meta_query to include all posts from your second post type.

Given in your example, you have 2 post types

1. events
2. news

If you can pick a `meta_key` that only exists for `news` but doesn't exist on `events`, then this set of args would return all news post types and still filter on events.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'news', 'events' ),
    'meta_key'  => 'end-date',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array( 
          'key'   => 'end-date',
          'value' => date ( 'Ymd' ),
          'type'  => 'NUMERIC',
          'compare' => '>='
        ),
        array(
          'key'      => 'my_unique_key_for_news',
          'compare'  => 'EXISTS'
        ),
        'relation' => 'OR',
    )
);
```

The `relation => OR` is important. It says please return results that fit your `end-dates` that are `>=` today, OR all the items that match up on the key for `news` (which would be all news items).

This way you are getting specific about the meta_values for events, but returning all results for news, and thus the filter leaves the second post type alone.

Answer (score 0):

Since *news* has no custom fields, you'll probably have better luck with this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'news', 'events' ),
    'orderby' => 'end-date date',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array( 
          'key'   => 'end-date',
          'value' => date ( 'Ymd' ),
          'type'  => 'NUMERIC',
          'compare' => '>='
        ),
        array(
          'key'      => 'end-date',
          'compare'  => 'NOT EXISTS'
        )
    )
);
```

Similar to italiansoda's answer, the "OR" relationship will look for any results that satisfy either meta query with the first being specific to your *events* post type that use the *end-date* meta field, and the other will happily pull in any *news* post types where that meta field doesn't exist.

Furthermore, I've found that by including **"meta_key" => "end-date"** in the top-level array of $args also excludes the *news* post type. I can't tell if it's working or just coincidence that my results are ordered correctly when using **"orderby" => "end-date date"**, essentially setting preference to order results first by the *end-date* meta field and then the post's publish date. But it's not breaking or excluding results with it.

Alternatively, you could do "multiple loops" to have specific control. It's not my favorite method by all means, but it works and gives you more control over the parameters for specific post types.

The first loop would be getting all of your *news* posts and returning them as an array of post IDs. How they're ordered or sorted doesn't matter here.

```
$news_ids = get_posts( array(
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'news',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    //Add any additional parameters specific to news here
));//Returns an array of IDs
```

The second loop would be getting all of your *events* posts and returning them as an array of post IDs. How they're ordered or sorted doesn't matter here either.

```
$events_ids = get_posts( array(
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array( array(
        'type' => 'NUMERIC',
        'key' => 'end-date',
        'value' => date( 'Ymd' ),
        'compare' => '>='
    ) ),
    //Add any additional parameters specific to events here
));//Returns an array of IDs
```

Using those two arrays, you can merge them into a "master list" of post IDs to then use as the value for **post__in** in the $args array. The order of the IDs still don't matter here.

```
$all_ids = array_merge( $news_ids, $event_ids );//Combine all of the post IDs together into one array

$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'news', 'events' ),//Specify both post types here still
    'post__in' => $all_ids,//Only display posts from the "master list" of IDs
    //Add any additional parameters for sorting all of them here like...
    'orderby' => 'end-date date',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
```

Order and sorting will be applied in your final and third "loop" when you define them in your $args array.